# Limitar cantidad de carácteres de un JTextField en java

Tags: java, jtextfield

Deseo limitar el ingreso de caracteres en un JTextField de java, y para eso utilice el siguiente código que también me permite espaciar en el txtfield para que vano contabilice también el espacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limito el ingreso de caracteres con el siguiente código. donde el 30 es el limite que configura cada uno según su necesidad. Y también agrego **java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE** para que permita espaciar.

```
    private void aLongitud(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                           
    if (nombreTextField.getText().trim().length() == 30 || evt.getKeyChar() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        evt.consume();}
```

Comment: Hola Padaleiana, me autorespondi la pregunta. Para guardar el codigo. Nose como dejarlo claramente. Pero ahi puse la respuesta.